# React, JS - functionality difference in different ways of using refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the difference between the following? Particularly in terms of functionality?

```js
<div ref={this.myRef}/>
```

```js
<div ref={(elem) => {this.myRef = elem;}}/>
```

When I do the second of the above and call `this.myRef.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})`, the scrolling behavior works. However, after changing it to the first, it doesn't work.

Comment: What does the rest of the component look like? Are you using `createRef` in the first case?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to provide complete examples for both cases, including the constructor, render method and usage.

Comment: @TomFenech, I'm using `createRef` in both cases.

Comment: If you want a definitive answer, you need to add a complete example to your question.

Answer (score 1):

in first case you have link to the div in `this.myRef.current` when it mounts to DOM.

in second case you pass function as ref.
This function will receive as first argument your node (div). And you can manipulate it in this function

```
<div ref={node => {
    console.log(node);
    // do something useful with node
}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without context, but probably `this.myRef` is not set in the first case. If you want to use the first option, you need to manually set it (by using something like `React.createRef()`), see the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) on this.

Comment: I'm already manually setting it with `React.createRef()` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The are same basically. But with the 2nd method you get more control. You can pass more parameters with the 2nd method.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.setTextInputRef = (element, name) => {
  this.textInput = element;
  this.x = name;
};
}
componentDidMount = () => {
if (this.textInput) {
  this.textInput.focus();
  console.log(this.x);
}
};

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <input
      placeholder="Input"
      ref={e => this.setTextInputRef(e, "hello")}
    />
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Run this example. Home this helps

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` prop provides you the element instance to set as React reference. When you do

```
<div ref={this.myRef} />
```

nothing is set as the reference so the variable `this.myRef` don't know which element to store.

Otherwise

```
<div ref={(elem) => {this.myRef = elem;}}/>
```

This code provides you the element to store as reference by it's `elem` param. Now the `this.myRef` knows which element to store as reference.